# C# regex need to match URL with only first level

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This code for "http://ahaliagroup.com/ahh/abc"

```
\b(?:https?://|www)\S+\b
```

gives me

http://ahaliagroup.com/ahh/abc

I want to get the match for URL, containing only first level path. Need help

eg

http://ahaliagroup.com/ahh/abc   - false

http://ahaliagroup.com/ahh/      - match

http://ahaliagroup.com/ahh - match

http://ahaliagroup.com/abb - match

This is example fiddle
https://dotnetfiddle.net/YZ5BGI

Comment: fyi: These aren't sub-domains. They're just paths in the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace non-space sequence (`\S+`) with a pattern where slashes and non-slash sequences expressed explicitly. This will give control over the number of slash occurrences:

```
\b(?:https?:\/\/|www)[^\/\s]+\/[^\/\s]+\/?(?!\S)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oUgdZX/1

Comment: Thanks for the fast response

Comment: The " or ' is also present in the match, can you help to avoid that

Comment: You may add `'"` to `[^\/\s]`: [`\b(?:https?:\/\/|www)[^\/\s'"]+\/[^\/\s'"]+\/?(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/oUgdZX/2)

Comment: Thanks very much.